# Send string array to powershell in visual studio release task

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs, continuous-deployment

I use TFS 2018. in Powershell release task I send string to ps1 file as argument. in ps1 file I used  this code to split string to multiple string

```
if($QueueName -contains ','){
    $QueueItems= $QueueName -split ','
    Foreach($Item in $QueueItems){
        $thisQueue=Get-MsmqQueue -Name $Item
        if($thisQueue.Length -eq 0){
            New-MsmqQueue -Name $Item -QueueType Private
        }
    }
}
else{
    $thisQueue=Get-MsmqQueue -Name $QueueName
    if($thisQueue.Length -eq 0){
        New-MsmqQueue -Name $QueueName -QueueType Private
    }
}
```

If i send string like this "q1,q2,q3" in windows PowerShell IE works fine but in Deploy task, "if($QueueName -contains ',')" does not find ',' in the $QueueName and in else block i got Error "##[error]New-MsmqQueue : Invalid queue path name."

Sorry for my english.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Tested your script and have the same issue for the `else` part even in PowerShell ISE. Besides, How did you pass the parse string to $QueueName in the deploy task?

Comment: Thank you. I got the problem. You are right. I use -match "\," Instead of  -contains ',' and problem solved.

Comment: @Amir Hosein saadatmand, Would you please share your solution as an answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issue to find the answer easily. Of course, please mark it as the answer.